# write in a csv file in python and read it using the column name

Tags: python, csv

while i have written this code

```
import csv
    with open('persons.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
        filewriter.writerow(['Name', 'Profession'])
        filewriter.writerow(['Derek', 'Software Developer'])
        filewriter.writerow(['Steve', 'Software Developer'])
        filewriter.writerow(['Paul', 'Manager'])
```

and i am getting the result as

```
['Name', 'Profession']
[]
['Derek', 'Software Developer']
[]
['Steve', 'Software Developer']
[]
['Paul', 'Manager']
[]
```

it is leaving a line in between.
how to resolve it ???

And one more thing i want to read  the data from csv using their column name i.e.

```
import csv
with open('persons.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
 
  
    for Name, Profession in reader:
        print(Name, Profession)
```

--when i run this code it shows error..

```
 for Name, Profession in reader:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

please suggest how it can work

Comment: I checked your code and my csv file is correct

Comment: works ok for me too. The csv it creates is correct. It doesnt look like what you've posted. To me that output looks like the result of using `print` inside list comprehensions.

Comment: Please do not ask new questions by editing old questions. If you have a new question about saving as `jpeg`, post it as a new question. Otherwise the existing `csv` answer won't make any sense to future readers.

Comment: @tdy unaable to ask a new question

Comment: i see, i guess due to previous downvotes. i just upvoted both of your posts, but not sure if that will be enough to lift the restriction.

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: could you please help me out. I have few questions to ask

Comment: unfortunately i don't have that kind of power. based on this post, it seems even moderators can't lift the restriction: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/1024093)

Answer (score 2):

`csv.writer` writes \r\n into the file by default. Use the following to open the file if you are running Windows

```
with open('persons.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
```

Once you have this, the empty lines will go away

The second issue is due to the first. Since you had empty lines, reader has 0 items for those lines, and hence the exception.